# Limiting characters in textarea on type and paste with ascx page

Tags: javascript

Here is the code which not supporting in IE 7 and 8 versions. Is there any workaround for this.

Help is appreciated and thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('textarea').on('input', function () {
        CharLimit(this, 400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxlength` attribute in your `<textarea>` element. No need to use Jquery for this:

```html
<textarea maxlength='5'></textarea>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp supports all browsers, check the table